# How do i make Google embedded calendar have some calendars not visible by default?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, google-calendar-api

ok i am trying to make an embedded Google calendar have some of the calenders that it is showing to be not viable until the user goes to the top corner of the calender to where there is already a drop down checkbox list with the calendars names.

i have come to the conclusion that javascript is needed however i can only access the  `<body>` portion of the HTML code

the embedded Google calendar is in an `<iframe>` as you would expect and here is the code for it:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/calendar/embed?showTitle=0&amp;height=600&amp;wkst=1&amp;bgcolor=%23FFFFFF&amp;src=e63g36qa5nqqi9opb2suv7ikck%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23875509&amp;src=u5ei2fappmnpv6a04pmuolmdl8%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23B1440E&amp;src=ec3r1i8moit23jp7u4jnd6jjj4%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%23B1365F&amp;src=avqo4ron8pus39vp33qrt5hpg0%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%235229A3&amp;src=nci5d26158dm0f0omhpl55ieck%40group.calendar.google.com&amp;color=%232F6309&amp;ctz=Europe%2FLondon" style="" height="600" width="800" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Comment: Believe you have some quotation marks you should remove in your `iframe` tag. Between `<` and `iframe`

Comment: the quotation marks are not there on the website i am working on and i have now removed them from this website as well

Comment: Can you make a fiddle? [here](http://jsfiddle.net)